# Is it wrong to downvote people for answering questions that ought to be nuked?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Especially when they should know better:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356890/what-is-the-use-of-f-what-is-the-purpose-of-f

PS: And someone wants to reopen it!

Comment: Obviously, if you think *this* one should be nuked, don't answer :)

Comment: I've noticed that [tag:f#] and [tag:r] often have many reopen votes for questions that should be closed.

Answer (score 10):

It is never wrong to downvote.

Comment: Not me, but you did ask for that :)

Comment: It's just people disagreeing, it's not wrong at all.

Comment: @Juan atta boy, sticking to your guns

Comment: Paradox: downvote this answer to show that is wrong to downvote ;-).

Comment: Is it therefore wrong to never downvote?

Comment: @Adam, no. *When* you downvote, it's not wrong.

Comment: Agreed.  Downvoting shouldn't be taken personally (nor should it be meant to be taken personally when applied).  It's simply a way for the system to self-correct.  If an answer or question is unhelpful, poorly presented, or in any number of ways not a constructive addition to the community then downvoting is simply the community's way of expressing that.

Answer (score 6):

If the OP has a fair amount of rep then I tend to downvote - they should really know better. Having lots of questions that are the same is not awesome so the question is not awesome - it is very bad.

If they are a new user, I will probably just vote to close and add comment hinting that they maybe should have spent a few minutes searching etc.

However, if the question is a question that has been repeated many times over and it's pretty obvious the OP didn't bother searching at all then it's an immediate downvote from me.

Just my 2¢

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about people who *answer* questions when they ought to be closing them.

Comment: @Benjol - I think what I have said still applies to answers too :) Especially if they answer *after* the close vote has been cast

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's wrong. I've done it myself a few times, usually only when a high-Rep user (10k or above) answers a question that is pretty clearly out of bounds.

Note that when you hover over the downvote arrow it says "This answer is not useful", and an answer from a high-ranking site user on a nuke-worthy question is just that: *not useful*. In my opinion, it sends the wrong message to other users on the site, because it is a tacit approval of the inappropriate question from an experienced user. In short, it sets a bad example, and usually I'll leave a comment when I downvote saying as such.

However, it should be noted that it can be easy to accidentally answer a duplicate without realizing. I probably wouldn't downvote for that, unless it is such an obvious many-times-over duplicate that they should have been able to find one with a trivial search. Not all duplicates are easy to find. I usually reserve this kind of "you should know better" downvoting for really off-topic or totally subjective poll questions.

Comment: "It sends the wrong message" is exactly what I thought. And in this case, it was a very low quality duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

I typically don't down-vote the answers because many times the one answering the question does not realize it is a duplicate or it is arguably an edge case type question.  They get more slack because they are less responsible for searching than the Asker.

If it is a super awful question, I might down vote.   I don't think it is wrong either way.